# avoiding group by for column used in datediff?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As the database is currently constructed, I can only use a Date Field of a certain table in a datediff-function that is also part of a count aggregation (not the date field, but that entity where that date field is not null. The group by in the end messes up the counting, since the one entry is counted on it's own / as it's own group.

In some detail:
Our lead recruiter want's a report that shows the sum of applications, and conducted interviews per opening. So far no problem. Additionally he likes to see the total duration per opening from making it public to signing a new employee per opening and of cause only if the opening could already be filled.
I have 4 tables to join:
 table 1 holds the data of the opening
 table 2 has the single applications
 table 3 has the interview data of the applications
 table 4 has the data regarding the publication of the openings (with the date when a certain opening was made public)

The problem is the duration requirement. table 4 holds the starting point and in table 2 one (or none) applicant per opening has a date field filled with the time he returned a signed contract and therefor the opening counts as filled. When I use that field in a datediff I'm forced to also put that column in the group by clause and that results in 2 row per opening. 1 row has all the numbers as wanted and in the second row there is always that one person who has a entry in that date field...

So far I haven't come far in thinking of a way of avoiding that problem except for explanining to the colleague that he get's his time-to-fill number in another report.

```
SELECT
table1.col1 as NameOfProject,
table1.col2 as Company,
table1.col3 as OpeningType,
table1.col4 as ReasonForOpening,
count (table2.col2) as NumberOfApplications,
sum (case when table2.colSTATUS = 'withdrawn' then 1 else 0 end) as   mberOfApplicantsWhoWithdraw,
sum (case when table3.colTypeInterview = 'PhoneInterview' then 1 else 0 end) as NumberOfPhoneInterview,
```

...more sum columns...,

```
table1.finished,   // shows „1“ if opening is occupied
DATEDIFF(day, table4.colValidFrom,  **table2.colContractReceived**) as DaysToCompletion

FROM
table2 left join table3 on table2.REF_NR = table3.REF_NR
join table1 on table2.PROJEKT = table1.KBEZ
left join table4 on table1.REFNR = table4.PRJ_REFNR

GROUP BY
**table2.colContractReceived**
```

and all other columns except the ones in aggregate (sum and count) functions go in the GROUP BY section

```
ORDER BY table1.NameOfProject
```

Here is a short rebuild of what it looks like. First a row where the opening is not filled and all aggregations come out in one row as wanted. The next project/opening shows up double, because the field used in the datediff is grouped independently...

```
project     company;    no_of_applications; no_of_phoneinterview;   no_of_personalinterview;    ... ;   time_to_fill_in_days;   filled?
2018_312    comp a      27                  4                       2                                   null                    0
2018_313    comp b      54                  7                       4                                   null                    0
2018_313    comp b      1                   1                       1                                   42                      1
```

I'd be glad to get any idea how to solve this. Thanks for considering my request!

(During the 'translation' of all the specific column and table names I might have build in a syntax error here and there but the query worked well ecxept for that unwanted extra aggregation per filled opening)

Comment: We can't see you're screen or access your data so can you include DDL and sample data that replicates the issue so that we can help.

Comment: As it is company data I can't just copy something. I do my best to add a table showing that - like writen - I get 2 instead of 1 row per opening/project.

Comment: Example result set added. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: We really need to see sample data (sanitized) that shows the problem, so that we can replicate it, and then try to solve it for you.  This means a few rows each from  --  table1, table2, table3, table4.  Only relevant columns need to be present to show the problem.  And your failing sql based on that sample that shows the problem.

Comment: Adding an aggregate function to DATEDIFF(day, table4.colValidFrom,  **table2.colContractReceived**) or both or it's parts doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: MAX(DATEDIFF(day, table4.colValidFrom, table2.colContractReceived)) OR DATEDIFF(day, MIN(table4.colValidFrom), MAX(table2.colContractReceived))

Comment: @Daniel Brughera: Yes! Works just fine since there's only one application in the joined table per opening that has the field ContractReceived filled out, I can use MIN oder MAX to avoid that column in the group by. Thanks a lot! That concept will be helpful in other cases as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your requirement properly, I believe the issue you are having is that you need to show the date between the starting point and the time at which an applicant responded to an opening, however this must only show a single row based on whether or not the position was filled (if the position was filled, then show that row, if not then show that row).

I've achieved this result by assuming that you count a position as filled using the "ContractsRecevied" column. This may be wrong however the principle should still provide what you are looking for.

I've essentially wrapped your query in to a subquery, performed a rank ordering by the contractsfilled column descending and partitioned by the project. Then in the outer query I filter for the first instance of this ranking.

Even if my assumption about the column structure and data types is wrong, this should provide you with a model to work with.

The only issue you might have with this ranking solution is if you want to aggregate over both rows within one (so include all of the summed columns for both the position filled and position not filled row per project). If this is the case let me know and we can work around that.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

```
declare @table1 table (
    REFNR int,
    NameOfProject nvarchar(20),
    Company nvarchar(20),
    OpeningType nvarchar(20),
    ReasonForOpening nvarchar(20),
    KBEZ int
);

declare @table2 table (
    NumberOfApplications int,
    Status nvarchar(15),
    REF_NR int,
    ReturnedApplicationDate datetime,
    ContractsReceived bit,
    PROJEKT int
);

declare @table3 table (
    TypeInterview nvarchar(25),
    REF_NR int
);

declare @table4 table (
    PRJ_REFNR int,
    StartingPoint datetime
);

insert into @table1 (REFNR, NameOfProject, Company, OpeningType, ReasonForOpening, KBEZ)
values (1, '2018_312',    'comp a' ,'Permanent', 'Business growth', 1),
       (2, '2018_313',    'comp a', 'Permanent', 'Business growth', 2),
       (3, '2018_313',    'comp a', 'Permanent', 'Business growth', 3);

insert into @table2 (NumberOfApplications, Status, REF_NR, ReturnedApplicationDate, ContractsReceived, PROJEKT)
values (27, 'Processed', 4, '2018-04-01 08:00', 0, 1),
       (54, 'Withdrawn', 5, '2018-04-02 10:12', 0, 2),
       (1, 'Processed', 6, '2018-04-15 15:00', 1, 3);

insert into @table3 (TypeInterview, REF_NR)
values ('Phone', 4),
       ('Phone', 5),
       ('Personal', 6);

insert into @table4 (PRJ_REFNR, StartingPoint)
values (1, '2018-02-25 08:00'),
       (2, '2018-03-04 15:00'),
       (3, '2018-03-04 15:00');



       select * from
       (
       SELECT
        RANK()OVER(Partition by NameOfProject, Company order by ContractsReceived desc) as rowno,
        table1. NameOfProject,
        table1.Company,
        table1.OpeningType,
        table1.ReasonForOpening,
        case when ContractsReceived >0 then datediff(DAY, StartingPoint, ReturnedApplicationDate) else null end as TimeToFillInDays,
        ContractsReceived Filled 


        FROM
        @table2 table2 left join @table3 table3 on table2.REF_NR = table3.REF_NR
        join @table1 table1 on table2.PROJEKT = table1.KBEZ
        left join @table4 table4 on table1.REFNR = table4.PRJ_REFNR

        group by NameOfProject, Company, OpeningType, ReasonForOpening, ContractsReceived, 
        StartingPoint, ReturnedApplicationDate
        ) x where rowno=1
```

Comment: Hi Dwight, thanks a ton for your time and thought. I try that RANK OVER in combination with Partition by out next chance I'm in the office.